# Unable to call firebreath dll functions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, firebreath

My firefox plugin is written using firebreath framework. It works absolutely fine upto version 28 of firefox. For higher versions I was unable to call the functions of firebreath dll from my javascript page only through firefox plugins. It works perfect in sample html file. I have also attached my source code for your reference.

Call to firebreath dll functions:

```
var plugin = document.getElementById('dllID');
if(plugin.valid)
{
    var ngInfo = plugin.ReturnUsers(param1, param2);
    if(ngInfo.length >0)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Overlay.xul:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/"?>
<overlay id="guardOverlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://guard/content/ngContent.js"/>
    <vbox style="height:0;">
        <html:embed type="application/x-guard" id="guard" style="height:0;"/>
    </vbox>
</overlay>
```

On catching exception it shows,
TypeError:plugin.ReturnUsers is not a function

Does anyone know the solution to my problem??

Comment: Is it a binary file? Or are you calling it with js-ctypes? Binary was deprecated and you need to move to js-ctypes: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/05/04/dropping-support-for-binary-components/comment-page-1/#comment-215903

Comment: Which platform(s)? Windows, Mac, Linux?  In windows they may have gone to 64 bit plugins at firefox 28

Comment: It is written for windows platform

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that you've ended up running a 64 bit version of firefox; 64 bit versions of firefox only run 64 bit versions of a plugin.  Try either installing a 32 bit version of firefox 28 or rebuilding your plugin as 64 bit.